# How to enable Excel vba combobox to update automatically

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am creating a user form that deals with inventory for a school project.

I created a combo box to delete selected items but i have no idea how to update the list after deleting a certain item. I am using the following code to perform the delete and refresh functionionality.

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    Dim row As Long
    row = cbPCodeIM.ListIndex + 2

    Sheets("Inventory").Select
    Sheets("Inventory".Range("A" & row & ":E" & row).Select
    Selection.Delete shift:=x1Up
    'the following line does not seem to work when uncommented
    'cbPCodeIM.ListFillRange = "=Inventory!$A$1:index(Inventory!$A:$A;CountA(Inventory!$A:$A))"
    MsgBox "Item has been removed.", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it's best to create a separate method for filling the `combobox` that you can then call from the `Initialize` event, and also whenever the `combobox` should be updated.

The code behind the `userform` would look like the following, with code to capture the `cmdDelete-Click()` event, the `Userform_Initialize()` event, and finally the custom method.

Let me know of any questions.

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    Dim nRow As Long

    nRow = Me.cbPCodeIM.ListIndex + 2
    Worksheets("Inventory").Rows(nRow).Delete 'NOTE, this will delete the entire row

    Fill_My_Combo Me.cbPCodeIM

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Fill_My_Combo Me.cbPCodeIM
End Sub


Private Sub Fill_My_Combo(cbo As ComboBox)
    Dim wsInventory As Worksheet
    Dim nLastRow As Long
    Dim i as Long

    Set wsInventory = Worksheets("Inventory")
    nLastRow = wsInventory.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Finds last row in Column 1

    cbo.clear
    For i = 2 To nLastRow 'start at row 2, assuming a header
        cbo.AddItem wsInventory.Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This code is faulty because it doesn't clear the combobox's list before repopulating it, so it will just add items to the existing list.  Also, the `Unload Me` will close the userform.  That should probably not be in the Delete button's code

Comment: @tigeravatar: Valid points. I edited my post to clear the combobox before repopulating it. I also removed the `Unload Me` snippet which I lumped in there during testing.  Thanks for the vigilance!

Comment: Much better, but still won't compile. Need to remove the `Me` from `Me.cbo.clear` because you passed the combobox as an object variable, so there is no need to use `Me` when calling it to clear it.  As a side note, I would also recommend `Dim i As Long` as well so that the loop counter variable is declared.  That part isn't super necessary, just good practice.

Comment: There we go, now all the bugs are out!  +1 for perseverance, and I would have provided basically the same solution if yours wasn't already here :)

Comment: If i have another question. Do i ask it here or create a new tread?

Comment: If it's a different question, it's best to start a new thread so things don't become cluttered

Comment: alright! you guys are awesome! really appreciate the help and advices! kudos to both of you